# Is this question too broad?

Tags: support, questions

I'm asking because I don't know if it would fit on https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ .

> I'm quitting my job on short notice as a developer concepter. As I've
>   been in charge of several projects, how can I make sure that the
>   company won't have much trouble ("when we are gone let happen what
>   may").   I finished the projects I had, I still have 2 days to do.

Is it good enough? Isn't it too broad?

Comment: FWIW a lot of more concrete questions like that have been [asked and answered in knowledge-transfer tag at Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knowledge-transfer?sort=frequent&pageSize=50)

Comment: If you left off the words "as a developer concepter" it would look like several other questions on Workplace, and thus would seem to fit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[As gnat said](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2329/what-can-i-do-to-simplify-my-departure#comment3821_2329), this may be more appropriate to Programmers.se than it is here.

As explained in our [help center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), questions asking how to perform the duties of your job are generally off-topic here. If you want to ask generically, [how can I prepare for not being around?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9128/how-can-i-prepare-for-getting-hit-by-a-bus) which is a rather company-agnostic question, it is likely okay. If you want to ask about your specific role and the specific details that concern you as a developer, it may be more productive at programmers.

So if you want the general explanation, read the bus question, and if that doesn't cover what you're talking about, ask away! If you want to get more specific about what you should do as a developer, you may want to take gnat's suggestion.